# Line break Twig question

Tags: 8, theming

I want to add line breaks in title field
I managed to use the replace functions in the template >

```
{{ node.getTitle()|replace({'|': '<br />'}) }}
```

Replacement works, but outputs the field as non-HTML. Do you know about a way to force an HTML output? Or any other way to be the 
 a real line break instead?

Comment: Have you tried the `raw` filter already? `{{ node.getTitle() | replace({'|': '<br />'}) | raw }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should help to use the raw filter, like @leymannx [commented](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290954/line-break-twig-question#comment364448_290954), but then your template is unsafe, because you should never use the raw filter on template variables containing user input.

So [escape](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/escape.html) the node title first, then add the HTML (which you know is safe because it's hardcoded), before passing it through the raw filter:

```
{{ node.getTitle()|e|replace({'|': '<br />'})|raw }}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It worked rightaway.