# How do I render content "as is" from custom controller

Tags: 8

I've created a custom controller that pulls content from another node (the body). That content is defined in the node as Raw HTML.

```
  public function page(Request $request): array {

    $nid = $request->attributes->get('_nid');
    $node_storage = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
    $node = $node_storage->load($nid);
    $content = $node->get('field_content')->value;

    // Load Entity using passed NID from key.
    $build = $content;
    // Return new Response($build);
    $render_array['snippet'] = [
      '#theme' => 'webpart_snippet',
      '#content' => $build,
      '#prefix' => '<div class="webpart_outer_wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];
    return $render_array;

  }
```

I would like to render that content as if it were a native Symfony response. (e.g., correctly parse and HTML tags AND scripts)

In the node that I'm pulling in, I have, for example

```
<h1>This is text</h1>
```

and that is exactly what is showing on the page

It should be

## This is text

I have defined a custom theme as well as twig template

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 * Declare a new theme
 */
function custom_webpart_snippet_theme() {
  return [
    'webpart_snippet' => [
      'variables' => [
        'content' => '',
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: What is `$render_array['snippet']`? Shouldnt it just be $render_array['content'] and some renderable arrays?

Comment: Could you not skip the theme hook and twig, and simply do `#type => markup, #markup => $build` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a text area field, you need to specify a type of render element, [processed_text](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21filter%21src%21Element%21ProcessedText.php/class/ProcessedText/8.2.x).

```
$render_array['snippet'] = [
  '#theme' => 'webpart_snippet',
  '#type' => 'processed_text',
  '#text' => $node->field_content->value,
  '#format' => $node->field_content->format,
  '#prefix' => '<div class="webpart_outer_wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
];
```

Comment: @stevekeiretsu I tried that and it gets me very close. The problem that still remains with that is that the node contains javascript (yup, I know - bad idea, but I have to work with it for now).  So... the remaining issue is that the javascript simply gets displayed (rather than being executed)... 

So - what now?

Comment: it contains `<script></script>` elements?  I can't think offhand why, if an `<h1>` is now being interpreted as a heading and not quoted/escaped as markup, a script tag would behave any differently.  I would expect it to work (yucky as it is).  Not sure what else to suggest without setting up a whole environment to replicate your data etc, I'm afraid.  Maybe drupal has some safety mechanisms I'm not aware.  Actually, come to think of it, are you sure the script tags survive into `$build` and are not being filtered by field text format settings?  No, wait, they must do if you see it displayed

Comment: @sea26.2 is your field's format set to full html? You could try hard coding it, `'#format' => 'full_html',`

Comment: @NoSssweat It is set to Raw HTML.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu You're right about Drupal Safety mechanism. According to api.drupal.org "#markup: (string) During rendering, this will be set to the HTML markup output. It can also be set on input, as a fallback if there is no theming for the element. This will be filtered for XSS problems during rendering; see also #plain_text and #allowed_tags."

Comment: Ah makes sense.  Well I suppose you could bypass drupal by doing something like `return new Response()->setContent($build)` but then you would be losing the whole drupal page template / theme / caching etc unless you reimplemented loads of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the template (twig)
Simply the ***raw*** filter
[see doc description here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html)

**Non-working code**

```
<div class="snippet-wrapper">
  <div>{{ content }}</div>
</div>
```

**Working code**

```
<div class="snippet-wrapper">
  <div>{{ content | raw }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since it contains user entered text maybe escape it fist for security reasons. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/290957/15055. `{{ content | escape | raw }}`.

Comment: Nice to know you found a solution. Although, I will say that it's not best practice to have scripts on your field. Ideally, you should include the script via a library.

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks!  And I agree. It is actually a really bad idea to put scripts inline within a field.  It wasn't my idea and I didn't do it :)